# I tried to set up swift editing vim with sourcekit-lsp but vim-lsp keep saying sourcekit-lsp is not installed

Tags: swift

I began to study swift with macbook pro 13 few weeks ago.
I really enjoy developing with xcode but I want to try with vim.
So I installed xcode 11.4 beta which includes toolchain in it.
and I clone sourcekit-lsp and build it.

after that I did neovim's init.vim's setting.

```
Plug 'prabirshrestha/async.vim'¬
Plug 'prabirshrestha/vim-lsp'¬
Plug 'ryanolsonx/vim-lsp-swift'¬

if executable('sourcekit-lsp')¬
    au User lsp_setup call lsp#register_server({¬
        \ 'name': 'sourcekit-lsp',¬
        \ 'cmd': {server_info->['sourcekit-lsp']},¬
        \ 'whitelist': ['swift'],¬
        \ })¬
endif¬
```

after that I installed plugins

finally when I open swift file
vim-lsp say "Sorry, `sourcekit-lsp` is not installed. See `:help vim-lsp-swift` for more details on setup."

when I run with command "`crun sourcekit-lsp`" terminal says nothing.

Installing sourcekit-lsp require more steps?

if anyone have knowledge on installing sourcekit-lsp on mac correctly please help me.

thanks for reading! have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

If you already had Xcode 11.4+ find the path of the sourckit-lsp using this command:

```
xcrun -f sourcekit-lsp
```

It will show something like this

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/sourcekit-lsp

Then add to your path:

```
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I was trying to use VSCode.

When you ran `swift build` it built the LSP server on the `.build/debug/` dir. So, you should add `sourcekit-lsp` to the path:

```
export PATH="$PATH:PATH_TO_LSP/sourcekit-lsp/.build/debug/"
```

This article might be helpful: https://rderik.com/blog/setup-swift-lsp-and-vim/